# Prove limit is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

How do I prove this result?

> $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\operatorname{li}(1-\varepsilon)-(1-\varepsilon)\ln\ln\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}\right]=\gamma$$with$$\operatorname{li}(x):=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}$$

[*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%28x-%3E0%2B%29%28li%281-x%29-%281-x%29ln%28ln%281%2F%281-x%29%29%29%29) obtains this limit.